# How to add datepicker in tpl file sugarcrm

Tags: sugarcrm

I want to add start date and end date field in the datepicker format in my tpl file. How can I do it using jQuery? And how to include jQuery coding in the tpl file?.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the code for a date time field in the file: include\SugarFields\Fields\Datetime\EditView.tpl.

The JavaScript code can be inserted the same way as in a .html file. The only difference is the brackets, ldelim for "{" and rdelim for "}".

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Calendar.setup ({ldelim}

{rdelim}
);
</script>
```